# Yarn - ARR- URLRewrite - Troubles with web, runnin fine with yarn on localhost:3030 but not on mydomain.com (urlredirect aar to localhost:3030)

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, hadoop-yarn, aar

Im trying to run a code by KPlaySearch on my IIS Windows webserver 2008 R2 or 2016.
I installed Git, Yarn install and yarn start, now, within my webserver, if I connectto localhost:3030 it runs the web ok and search is done ok.

But if I run externally, the domain web (http://xn--ida.gt/google/play/adsfree/) has configured URLrewrite to redirect to localhost:3030. The same website is shown to me (as if I were on localhost:3030 on webserver) so seems ok,  but when I hit on the search box of KPlaySearch (NOT the first one in a iframe, so the bottom one) the search does not work. So something is not working.

What can I do ?

Comment: What? AAR or ARR?

Comment: ARR, so yes, sorry I meant ARR

Comment: Then try to see if FRT can reveal the cause, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Your proposal seems not valid, as , once I installed and add an FRT rule, it ask me to specify which kind of error I would like to trace (404.2, ..) but I dont know which error is happening. I only know that on localhost:3030 the engine works as expected, but once using a redirect via URLRewrite, the web is show but the search engine of KPlaySearch does not work.

So, Do I need to trouble with FRT ? if so, if yes, for which kine of error / status code ?

Comment: Ironically, that article shows you how to track all requests/responses (not just errors) if you spend even a minute on it.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: It was nothing to do with ARR
Issue is that original developer uses ROOT relative paths, and as Im using the code under a webdomain/path1/path2.. it wasn't work. Resolved, changing on index.js the paths "/categories" and "/search" for "categories" and "search"

https://git.kaki87.net/KaKi87/KPlaySearch/issues/19#issuecomment-333

Comment: Please mark the answer so that it can help others with similar problems.

Comment: How can I mark an answer as accepted ? in this case my own answer